# Why `console.log(x = y)` prints the value of `x` instead of `y`?

Tags: javascript

I need come feedback and an explanation for the following quiz I encountered:

`x = 10, y = 20` and finally `x = y`

If we consider `x` and `y` as variables and the `=` operator standing for 'assignment'. What are the values of `x` and `y`?

After doing some basic reasoning on what I learnt about variables and values, I've written the following code:

```
var y = 10;
var x = 20;
console.log(x = y);
```

The result printed out is 20. Is this process and reasoning giving the correct result? If it is I understand the process but I am not sure to know the reason why the result is 20. 
I would need some feedback and explanation on this matter.

Comment: Giving `10` on latest Chrome

Comment: Prints `10` on Chrome

Comment: You are not telling us everything. It's like you're trying to print the value of x after asign it as the same as y

Comment: `console.log(x = y)` does not really log what you may think it logs. I don't think it's a great idea to go into the details of what's *really* happening, so let's suffice it to say that you should do `x = y; console.log(x);` for the time being.

Comment: @deceze: in fact `console.log` is non-standard, so who knows what it does? (Rhetorical question which has an actual answer: "the guy who designed the implementation") Still, I'm very curious to know why and under what circumstances it should log `20`. Please continue :)

Comment: @Tobia Well, it shouldn't, under any circumstances. The result of logging `x = y` or `x` afterwards should be identical, but only coincidentally for this particular operation. Other operations may yield very different results.

Comment: I thought the correct process was to log the result by using the console.log function. It turned out to be a mistake. In fact, if i write the code on sublimetext and then see the result on firefox, it will show nothing by using console.log. Instead, if i use the alert function it shows the result on the web browser. Thank you all for your feedback

Comment: @FrancescoPalma: that's... surprising. Are you sure you have enabled the console in Firefox?

Comment: @TobiaTesan I'm not sure if I've ever enabled the console actually. By console you mean the one you open by selecting tools->web developer->web console?

Comment: Yes. `console.log` should indeed log to the, er, console. Of course if you just save the above code in a file and open it in firefox it will not do anything, but if you paste it to the console or have your webpage run it, it will.

Comment: @TobiaTesan thank you again! I finally understood, I didn't use the console on Firefox and that's why our results were not the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are lying or your implementation of JavaScript is broken :)

According to [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1):

> The production AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression =
>   AssignmentExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 3. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 4. Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true:
>
>    - Type(lref) is Reference is true
>    - IsStrictReference(lref) is true
>    - Type(GetBase(lref)) is Environment Record
>    - GetReferencedName(lref) is either "eval" or "arguments"
> 5. Call PutValue(lref, rval).
> 6. Return rval.

So `x = y` **should be evaluated to the value assumed by `x` after the assignment**, which is to say, the value of `y`: `10`.

As a side note, this feature of the language is particularly useful for doing something like:

`min = max = 0`

Thereby assigning to `min` the result of the evaluation of `max = 0`, which is to say, `0`.

Comment: Can't we do better than accuse beginners of lying?

Comment: I recognize that this answer is very complete :)

Comment: @deceze: of course it's meant in a jocular manner. I'll add a smiley to clarify. Then again, logic dictates that it's indeed the former or the latter option :)

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the feedback. I'm using SublimeText as editor and the latest Firefox as web browser. if I write the following code: document.writeln("Hello World!");
var x = 10; 
var y = 20;
alert(x = y); --> It prints out 20. Am I missing something? Sorry, I really am a beginner, thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @Francesco Well yes, if `y` is actually `20` then you'll get `20`. Compare with your actual question!

Comment: @FrancescoPalma: That's the correct behaviour, as specified by the standard, detailed in my answer above. Then again, if `x = 20` and `y = 10` as in the original question, it's supposed to be **the other way around** :)

Comment: Thank you guys! Now i finally understand how it works.

Answer (score 4):

The assignment operation in JavasScript is an expression and the value it returns is right side of the operation. The output for this piece of code is 10, as it's the value of `y`

Answer (score 1):

You are making something different that you tell.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nowoq16f/

Result is `10` as expected

```
var y = 10;
var x = 20;
alert(x = y);
```

Answer (score 0):

It outputs 10.

It firstly assigned y to x

Then output the result.

Answer (score -1):

The = operator in JavasScript assign an expression (left side) to the right side of the operator. So, the output should be 10.